# Can we create a GlobalSuppression.cs file for the complete solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, code-analysis, fxcop

I wanted to know that, In Visual Studio Code Analysis (same as FxCop), can we have a GlobalSuppression.cs file that is applicable for the whole solution and not only for the individual projects inside the solution.

If yes, then can you please suggest how we can create such a Suppression file?

Comment: Yes, it would be possible, but it's a bit of an odd request given that suppressions are targeted at individual issues, which are located in particular assemblies (i.e.: there's not really much point in trying to span assemblies with a single file in this case).  Is there some particular reason you're attempting to do this?  (I'm just wondering if there might not be a better approach to meeting your target goal.)

Answer (score 1):

You can [link Global suppression file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92.aspx) within Visual Studio across projects. So the same file will be shared. A simple Drag drop of the file by pressing `Alt` key into whichever project you need the file will do.

Comment: Are you able to create GlobalSuppression.cs file for a project? If you have successfully created for one project. Add it to the rest of the projects by dragging and dropping them from the source project by clicking Alt button. Then the same file will exist across all projects.

Comment: So does that solve the problem, are you still getting suppression errors?